# カレンダー予約の時間がずれてしまいます

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Google Form を使ってカレンダーの設備予約をする、というコードを作成したのですが、なぜか時間がずれてしまいます。

例えば16:00～17:00で予約すると、16:37～17:37で予約が入ってしまいます。また、他の予約でも予約はなぜか37分ずれてしまいます。
GASの標準時間もカレンダーの時間も東京にしているのですが、どなたか原因をご存じの方いらっしゃいますでしょうか。

Comment: 実際のコードを質問中に追記してください。

Answer (score 0):

スプレッドシートのタイムゾーン設定がスクリプトのタイムゾーン設定とは別にあり、どういうわけかこれが dili (東ティモール) になってしまう場合があるようです。 フォームに紐づけたスプレッドシートの設定を見直してみてください。

それで 37 分のずれとなって現れるのが何故なのかはよくわかっていないようですが東京に設定することで解決したという事例がネット検索するといくつか見つかります。

Comment: スプレッドシート側の問題でしたか、、、おっしゃる通りスプレッドシートの時間を東京にすることで解決しました。ありがとうございます！